# Encryption credentials have expired when trying to print to network printer on macOS 12.6 (Monterey)

Tags: mac, printer

I am trying print on my iMac running macOS 12.6 (Monterey) to a network printer.

I've never had issues adding printers or using network printers on a Mac.

The Mac was working fine, I then took my Mac home over the holidays, and when I returned to the office I am now getting “Encryption credentials have expired” message when trying to print.

[image]

If I click the help icon it just says this.

[image]

I've found a this article online about this and they are saying...

https://appletoolbox.com/encryption-credentials-have-expired-mac/

- “On your Mac, go to System Preferences.” **DONE**
- “Select Printers and Scanners.” **DONE**
- “Locate and select your printer in the list.” **DONE**
- “Then hit the Remove button.” **DONE**
- “Printers & Scanners System Preferences add and minus buttons Remove and re-add your printer from the Printers & Scanners System Preferences.” **DONE**
- “Click on Delete Printer to remove the device.” **DONE**
- “Navigate to `/Library/Printers` and drag your printer folder to Trash.” **CANT DELETE THIS, BUT FOLDER IS EMPTY ANYWAY**
- “Empty the Trash folder, turn off your Mac and unplug your printer.” **NO POINT DOING THIS BECAUSE I COULDN'T DELETE**
- “Restart your devices, and go back to Printers and Scanners.” **RESTARTED PRINTER**
- “Find and install your printer, but this time change the driver from Secure AirPrint to AirPrint.” **TRIED THIS BUT GIVES ME NO OPTION TO CHANGE DRIVER**

[image]

I installed the printer and printer software anyway by via Bonjour, like I've always done.

[image]

I've gone to do a test print, and I’m getting exactly the same message.

[image]

But the scanner works fine!

Please does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Here is an idea: Download and run [Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html) to clear out old macOS caches. Download it, launch it as any other app, go to the “Maintenance” tab and run all of the maintenance items that are checked. The system will reboot with caches cleared and that _might_ shake out any stray stuff that would interfere would have caused this issue.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 ok cool I will give this a whirl when I get back to my machine, is Onyx safe?

Comment: Yes, Onyx is very safe. It just purges caches and doesn’t put anything at risk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just ran into the same issue with my Epson WF-3620 printer. Owned this printer for about 10 years, had no issues until today. Suddenly, each of the Macs in my house (running various versions of macOS, some new, some *very* old) started getting this `Encryption credentials have expired` error when trying to print.

As it turns out, "10 years" was the big clue here. The printer has a Self-signed Certificate which it uses for SSL/TLS encryption over the network, which is only valid for a maximum of 10 years. This appears to be a default configuration provided by Epson.

Fortunately, there's a simple solution: **update the Self-signed Certificate using the printer's Web Config**. This will give the printer a new, valid certificate and prevent the error from blocking your prints.

Full guide from Epson [here](https://download4.epson.biz/sec_pubs/l6570_series/useg/en/GUID-EA3AAC53-31BC-4C47-80AE-072EED27B490.htm) (different model, but the steps should be the same for most Epson printers), or read on for my instructions below.

### How To Update the Self-signed Certificate

1. **Find your printer's local IP address on your network.**

   - You should be able to find this on the printer itself by navigating the settings and finding the "Wi-Fi/Network Information" screen.
   - Alternatively, depending on your version of macOS, you may be able to access the information on your Mac by going to "System Preferences" > "Printers & Scanners" > [Select your printer] > "Options & Supplies..." > "General" > "Show Printer Web Page..." > "Wi-Fi/Network" > "IP Address"
2. **Visit your printer's Web Config by opening its IP address in your web browser.**

   - Depending on your browser, you'll get some kind of "This connection is not private" warning.
   - Bypass the warning by clicking "Show Details" > "visit this website" (Safari), or "Show advanced" > "Proceed to [IP address]" (Chrome), or "Advanced..." > "Accept the Risk and Continue" (Firefox)
3. **From the Web Config, select: "Network Security" > "SSL/TLS" > "Certificate"**
4. **Click the "Update" button under "Self-signed Certificate".**

   - [Click here for a screenshot of the Web Config interface.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APGSb.png)
   - Note: if you click the "Confirm" button instead, you can view the details of your current certificate. I took a look at mine before updating, and what do you know, it expired `Dec 30 2022`!
5. **Follow the steps in the Web Config to update the Self-signed Certificate, and be sure to select "10 years" (or longer, if such an option is available to you) as the validity period.**
6. **Wait for the update to be applied, then remove and re-add the printer in each of your Macs' "Printers & Scanners" System Preferences pane.**
7. *(Optional) Set a reminder to update this again 10 years from now ;)*

And that's it! You should now be able to print without getting this error. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @mistryn for you detailed response, I clicked update on the SSL/TLS certificate. https://imgur.com/a/QKUpZq5 then clicked Next, OK. Waited for the restart to complete and tried printing and I am still get the same error.

Comment: @joshmoto you will likely need to delete and re-add the printer to your Mac in System Preferences for the Mac to see the new certificate. (System Preferences -> Printers & Scanners. Select the printer, then click the minus ‘-‘ button. Then click the plus ‘+’ button and add the printer again)

Comment: OK it is now working after re adding. Thank you that seemed to finally solve it! Cheers!

Comment: For anyone with a Dell E525w printer (or possibly other older Dell printers), the steps are the same until #4. Instead click "Certificate Management" then the small "Delete" button on the right. Confirm by clicking "Delete" again. Restart the printer and refresh the page. Go back through the steps to get to the SSl/TLS page. Now you will see a new option to generate a new certificate! Do it! And set the expiration date to very far in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I went to the Epson website, searched for my printer's drivers by name (in my case WF-3640) and installed the new drivers. After doing so, the problem was resolved. I needed to do this on both my Apple Desktop computer and my laptop.